# Populating drop-down based on previous selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have MySQL tables looking like that

regions table

```
id     |   region
-------------------
1      |   Region1
2      |   Region2
```

...

and schools table

```
id     |   school
-------------------
1      |   schno1
1      |   schno5
1      |   schno6
2      |   scho120
```

There are multiple select (dropdown) menus in my registration form. The regions dropdown looks like that

```
<select name="region">
<option value="0">Select the region</option>
<?php
$result=$db->query("SELECT * FROM regions");
while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

What i want to do is, get "regions" id, then populate schools dropdown menu based on id (id of previous selection) from "schools" table on the fly. I'm newbie to js. Please help me to fix it. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$region = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['region']);
$query = "SELECT s.school FROM regions r 
          INNER JOIN schools s ON (s.region_id = r.id) 
          WHERE r.region LIKE '$region' ";  <<-- LIKE is case insensitive, '=' is NOT 
$result = $db->query($query);
if not($result) then { die("error"); }
while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: it's the serverside part. and how to figure out client side part?

Answer (score 2):

1) Make use of jQuery change event (bind to region select)
2) Call your php script, where you should provide the schools data based on region id
3) Attach the data to school select

There are plenty of examples on www - http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: i'm newbie to js. I can't figure it out. please edit my code if you can.

Comment: Read the docs, read the examples, try things out. That's how you learn to do something.