# Populating a <select> then changing another <select> based off the original

Tags: php, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populating drop-down based on previous selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203860/populating-drop-down-based-on-previous-selection)

Okay here's basically what I'm attempting to do.  The first  statement is populated by a query of a table on the server.  The Second  has 3 values: Elite, Core, Raider.  Using AJAX and PHP I'm trying to make it so when someone selects a name from the first  the second one always changes to the value that is in the database for that person; however this must remain a select in case an unoted switch happens(in which case the value of the second  must be changed).

```
<?php
echo "<select name='playername' onchange='filldata(this.value)'>";
require("/home/a9299818/public_html/DKPTools/connect.php");
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT player.id, player.primarytoon, player.rank, IFNULL( SUM(dkp.dkp ) , 0 ) 
FROM player
LEFT OUTER JOIN dkp ON player.id = dkp.player_id
GROUP BY player.id
ORDER BY player.id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1, MYSQL_NUM)){printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$row[0],$row[1]);}
echo "</select>";
echo "<select name='rank'><option value='1'>Elite</option><option value='2'>Core</option><option value='3'>Raider</option>";
?>
```

This PHP works and populates both selects correctly; however I'm totally lost in coding the AJAX which should change rank.value to whatever the database says it is WITHOUT REFRESHING THE PAGE.

Comment: Not in this case, the values of the second drop down are static and the options do not change.  Only the Value should when the first is changed, but the value is still one of the first 3 options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities.

The first is to work with jQuery and Ajax.

```
function filldata(value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "URL_TO_PHP_FILE",
        data: "playerID=" + value,
        success: function(result) {
            $("select[name=rank]").val(result);
        }
    });
}
```

URL_TO_PHP_FILE is the url to the PHP file in which you retrieve the rank_id from your database for the player with the given playerID.
In the PHP file you should only echo the rank_id.
So the PHP file would look like this:

```
<?php ## THE PHP FILE ##
require("/home/a9299818/public_html/DKPTools/connect.php");
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT player.rank WHERE player.id = ".$_GET['playerID']);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query1, MYSQL_NUM);
echo $row['rank'];
## END OF PHP FILE ## ?>
```

The seconds possibility is to make sure the option value of your first select is not equal to the "player_id", but to the "rank_id". So you can write a javascript function..

```
function filldata(value) {
    $("select[name=rank]").val(value);
}
```